# Why is water draining back into washer hours after completing wash cycle and spinning dry?

Tags: washer

Washer is in basement. there is no slop sink for discharge of water,  hose goes up into the ceiling and out of the foundation to a drywell.  Lately some of the water back ups into the washer. I have a check valve (anti-backflow valve) , but it is still happening.  This is only recently, after 8 year of use.

Comment: I would imagine the check valve is not working right.  Maybe it is sticking from closing/sealing all the way.  Replacement might be cheaper/easier than trying for repair, unless it is just dirt.

Comment: If this hadn't been working for eight years I'd wonder if the washer pump was strong enough to overcome the elevation head.

Answer (score 2):

A washer drain should not have the ability to back-siphon.  Every washer I have had or seen (USA) discharges into a larger pipe via a discharge line loosely inserted into the pipe.  Any backup of the drain line would go to the floor, not the machine itself.

If you have a solid line out to a sewage line, a backup could result in water going back to the machine, including creating a siphon.  Your machine might also have a check valve or solenoid-operated file to prevent backflow that has failed, and if your discharge is into the ceiling, you would have a large volume of water in that discharge line constantly.